# How to input today date in the next cell in a row based on checkbox value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Im new to scrpting and found no content on the subject.

I need to write a script so whenever a check box on column M is checked,inputs today date on same row column N. And, if it already has a value, do nothing.
sheet as below:

[image: My sheet]

I dont know where to begin please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an onEdit(e) simple trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {  // Limit to a particular sheet
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 13 ) {  // Limit to column M
        if( e.value ) {
          if( e.range.offset(0,1,1,1).getValue() === "" ) {  // Cell is empty
            e.range.offset(0,1,1,1).setValue(new Date());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```